# Content type permissions are not working

Tags: 7

I'm trying to give users permission to edit certain content types, but it's not working. I'm having trouble tracking down which module could be the culprit. (I've used a couple of beta modules)

How should I go about tracking down this problem?

Comment: make sure you have proper permissions assigned.Try rebuilding the site permissions. If it still does not work try disabling individual permission based modules and rebuild site permission each time you do so and check. You can also try using the devel node access module which gives a block which is placed below each content.

Comment: This is a quite broad question, even if it is still possible to answer it.

Comment: Didn't know that devel has a permissions module. Very helpful. You can make that the anser and I'll mark it @junedkazi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you have proper permissions assigned.Try rebuilding the site permissions.

If it still does not work try disabling individual permission based modules and rebuild site permission each time you do so and check.

You can also try using the [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) node access module which gives a block which is placed below each content.